# How to use dbutils in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to mount an s3 bucket through DBFS, and none of these tutorials say what dependencies I need to add, and what I need to import to get it to work.

Say, here https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html you can see there is this "dbutils" object everywhere, but nowhere does it say what dependency I need to add and what I need to import to access it.

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 0):

`dbutils` is a proprietary Databricks product. To use it, you have to pay for the platform, and you'll get it out-of-the-box.

Otherwise there is no such option. It is not standalone package, and cannot be purchased or licenses outside Databricks analytic platform.